# Is it possible to specify the location of ".composer"?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Composer version: 0.16.3

It seems composer command by default create/update $HOME/.composer folder. Is it possible to change this folder ? For example, specify some environmental variable, then it create something like $HOME/.composer-stage, $HOME/.composer-production.  The purpose is to change the target. E.g. staging environment to production environment for .bna file upgrade.

I remember in 0.12.x, we were able to select connection profiles for target selection.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

so the question (and answer here) relates to Hyperledger Composer. The `.composer` directory represents the wallet or credentials store for business network cards relating to a user connecting to business network(s) whether via CLI, Playground, APIs, REST etc etc.  The current answer is no - not presently. See https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3121 as referred above.

Answer (score 0):

This is not available at present, but there is an Issue already logged on Github and it is being worked on [Hyperledger Composer Issue 3121](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3121) - In making the card store more generic it is likely that it will allow you to specify a folder name of your choice.